# Applying for a UK visa with a misdemeanor in the US

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, russian-citizens, criminal-records, us-permanent-residents

I am a citizen of Russia and a permanent resident of the United States. My ex-wife in the US obtained a restraining order against me and I was arrested for violating the order, which she claimed was cyberstalking on social media. There was no physical or sexual violence or threats of violence, but I was arrested and convicted of a misdemeanor. I was put on probation, but I did not go to jail. Now that my probation is over, do I have a chance of getting a tourist visa to the UK if I include all of my court-related documents with my application?

Comment: Per http://hub.unlock.org.uk/knowledgebase/travelling-uk/, it looks like you'll likely be inadmissible if less than 12 mo has passed since your conviction, but should/may be OK after that.